Rate of convergence of random samples wrt Hausdorff distance
Let $X$ be a compact metric space with a probability measure $\mu$. We can draw random samples $X_n = \{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$ from $X$ using $\mu$, and I am interested in the rate of convergence of $X_n$ to $X$ in the Hausdorff distance.
The paper Convergence rates for persistence diagram estimation in Topological Data Analysis (2014) says that this paper by Cuevas & Rodriguez-Casal (2004) gives the rate of convergence for the case $X=\mathbb{R}^d$, and the 2014 paper generalized it to a general metric space.
The 2014 paper proved that, if $\mu$ satisfies $(a,b)$-standard assumption i.e. $\mu(B(x,r))\geq \min\{ar^b,1\}$ for any $x\in X,r>0$, there exists two constants $C_1,C_2$ only depending on $a,b$ such that
$\begin{align} \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{\log{n}}\right)^{1/b}d_H(X,X_n)\leq C_1 \textrm{almost surely, and}\end{align}$
$\begin{equation}\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(d_H(X,X_n)\leq C_2 \left(\frac{\log{n}}{n}\right)^{1/b}\right) =1\end{equation}$
where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance.
My question is whether any later results improve/generalize this convergence rate. I briefly looked through the papers citing this paper, but they seem to be all about TDA with no focus on this convergence rate.

I think this bound is tight (the only doubt is in the exponent, but it would agree on manifolds so I suspect its correct).
The simplest proof I can think of would be to use the fact that the bottleneck distance between persistence diagrams is a lower bound for the Hausdorff distance. In that case, if you take a sample on a compact d-manifold, say a sphere, the distance between the d-dimensional persistence diagram of the space and the one of a random sample (assuming uniform measure) will be $\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^{1/d}$ and so the bound should be tight.
